# How to create custom pages for http 500 and 410 status errors?

Tags: 7, http-request

In the site information section in the configuration, there is an option for setting the 404 page. But How will I set a custom page for http 500 and 410 error pages?

Is there any specific module for this? OR I have to create a custom tpl file in some pattern? Any idea?

Comment: Have a read through this: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/35301/friendly-error-page-to-replace-wsod

Comment: that is for d8 i think.

Comment: It was asked in 2012 so that's very unlikely. The question even specifies Drupal 7, and the highest voted answer definitely applies to 7 only

Comment: 500 and 410 errors are probably best dealt with at the server level. Here's how to have custom errors in Apache:
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/custom-error.html